# run VBScript on multiple IPs

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS file that connects with telnet to some old hardware.
I want to run the VBS on multiple IPs.

What should I change in the telnet script in order to select IPs from a TXT file and run the script on each IP?

Something like the ping example below but without the output file.

Telnet VBS file:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "telnet"
WScript.Sleep 4000
oShell.SendKeys "open 192.168.194.82~"
WScript.Sleep 4000
oShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 4000
oShell.SendKeys "This is the password~"
WScript.Sleep 4000
oShell.SendKeys "system~"
WScript.Sleep 4000
oShell.SendKeys "restart~"
oShell.SendKeys "yes~"
WScript.Quit
```

Ping example:

```
Dim strInputPath, strOutputPath, strStatus
Dim objFSO, objTextIn, objTextOut 
strInputPath = "c:\ip-list.txt" '- location of input
strOutputPath = "c:\ip-list-output.csv" '- location of output 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputPath, 1)
Set objTextOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPath)
objTextOut.WriteLine("computer,status") 
Do Until objTextIn.AtEndOfStream = True
    strComputer = objTextIn.ReadLine
    If fPingTest(strComputer) Then
         strStatus = "UP"
    Else
         strStatus = "DOWN"
    End If
    objTextOut.WriteLine(strComputer & "," & strStatus)
Loop

Function fPingTest(strComputer)
    Dim objShell, objPing
    Dim strPingOut, flag
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objPing = objShell.Exec("ping " & strComputer)
    strPingOut = objPing.StdOut.ReadAll
    If InStr(LCase(strPingOut), "reply") Then
        flag = True
    Else
        flag = False
    End If
    fPingTest = flag 
End Function
```

Comment: Canonical answer: if you want to script telnet, use a telnet command that's actually scriptable, e.g. [`plink`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html). Everything involving `SendKeys` is unreliable at best and should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: PLINK didn't accept my commands this is the reason why i use sendkeys.